# How to shutdown a list of servers, making sure the first one is off before shutting down the next?

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a list of 17 servers in this format:

```
172.16.6.45    i-052463fs (test-mv1)
172.16.6.46    i-9e2263rf (test-mv2)
```

I'd like a script that can ssh/login to each and every of these servers and shut them down which is easy enough but the catch is that they need to be turned off in a particular order shown above (down the list) where each preceding one has to be completely turned off before the next shut down begins.

Perhaps a way put a loop behind the command that pings every n seconds and breaks when no reply is received within k seconds?

Comment: Do you want them _off the network_? or _off_ (which `ping` can't help you with)? Can the power status of those servers be controlled one way or the other remotely (like a virtualisation API if they are VMs or IPMI for physical machines)?

Comment: What operating system are those servers running? The command to shut them down and/or to power them off varies between Unix-like OSes.

Comment: I just created a script very similar to this because I wanted to shut down all VMs on my server and THEN shutdown the physical machine.  The best I could come up with was using ssh to issue the 'poweroff' command to the VMs, then waiting until ping failed to move to the next one.  See JdeHaan's answer for a start.

Comment: @RickChatham, in the case of VMs, you can monitor the power status of the VMs from the host (like watching `virsh list` for libvirt), you don't need to rely on the unreliable ping approach.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'd love a little more info on this, even if it has to go into another question, as I find using virsh a little like slamming my head into my desk.  Do you just do `virsh list` in a loop and wait until the list comes up empty?  It sounds like a MUCH BETTER idea.

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like:

```
while IFS=' (' read <&3 ip id name rest; do
  ssh -n -o ConnectTimeout=3 -o BatchMode=yes -o HostKeyAlias="$name" "$ip" poweroff &&
    while ping -qw 10 -c3 "$ip"; do
      sleep 1
    done
done 3< list.txt
```

A few notes on that code:

- We use the *name* part as the HostKeyAlias, maybe `$id` would make more sense. Ideally, you'd need something attached to the sshd server host key.
- We use `-n` for `ssh` and the BatchMode as we're doing an unattended script here. You may also want to specify a dedicate `UserKnownHostsFile` for that purpose.
- We don't run the `while` loop if `ssh` wasn't successful. You may also want to exit the script with an error in that case. You may also want to add an upper bound on the iterations of the while loop to account for servers failing to shut down.
- Our loop does 3 ping probes separated by 1 second, and gives up after 10 seconds. `ping` (at least the one from `iputils` on Debian will return true if at least one probe is answered which should cover for genuine packet loss. The one second delay between 2 out of 3 of thhe probes avoids flooding the server as a `while ping -c1` loop would do. The extra delay after the 3 probes have been sent and not answered hopefully gives the server enough time to shut down after it has torn down its IP stack.

Answer (score 2):

```
ssh host sudo shutdown -h -y now ; ping -c 1 host ; while [ $? = 0 ] ; do ping -c 1 host ; done
```